# What is the acid base reaction between hydrogen telluride and sulfide ion?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

$$\ce{H2Te + S^2- -> ?}$$

I tried this problem but I was confused on the fact of what the products would be because in my head I didn't think $\ce{STe}$ is a product and also it has to create water but there is no $\ce{OH-}$. Could someone assist me with this problem?

Comment: Why does it have to create water?

Comment: Although the Arrhenius definition of an acid-base reaction requires the formation of salt and solvent, the Brønsted–Lowry definition does not; it only requires that one species donate a proton to another.

Answer (score 2):

Observe this reaction:

$$\ce{Na2S + H2S → 2NaHS}$$

If you use sodium sulfide and react it with hydrogen sulfide, sodium hydrosulfide/bisulfide is formed.

Similarly, if you use sodium telluride and react it with hydrogen sulfide, it is expected to form sodium hydrogen telluride( $\ce{NaHTe})$.

Note that hydrogen telluride is an unstable acid but the acidified ion $\ce{HTe-}$ is quite stable. In fact, the sodium salt of hydrogen telluride ion is known, albeit not prepared through above reaction.

> The intermediate in the acidification, $\ce{HTe-}$, is a stable anion.
> Sodium hydrogen telluride, $\ce{NaHTe}$, can be made by reducing
> tellurium with $\ce{NaBH4}$. ([Hydrogen telluride](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_telluride))
>
> The acid hydride of tellurium, hydrogen telluride, $\ce{H2Te}$, is an
> unstable compound that decomposes to tellurium metal. It is strongly
> acidic, dissociating into a hydrogen telluride ion ($\ce{HTe-}$)
> in aqueous solutions. ([Telluride ion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telluride_(chemistry)))